# Cross domain iframe mic permissions changed in Safari 12.1?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, getusermedia

Safari 12.1 seems to have stopped remembering getUserMedia (microphone in this case) permissions for cross domain iframes.

Given a simplified example of two sites:

Domain A:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <button onclick="triggerUserMedia()">Get User Media</button>

        <script>
            function triggerUserMedia(){
                const constraints = { audio: true, video: false };
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
                .then(function(stream) {
                    console.log('got stream');
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log('couldn\'t get the stream');
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Domain B:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://domain-a/index.html" allow="microphone"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Safari pre 12.1, and in the current build of Chrome etc., pressing the button multiple times when embedded in Domain B would result in one single "Allow “Domain A” to use your microphone?", just on the first press.

However, it now results in a permission popup every time the button is pressed.

Does anyone know what specifically changed in Safari 12.1 which is caused this behaviour to change? (Is this a new webkit security restriction?)

What can be done to ensure the permission is only asked for once, as it was before?

(We call getUserMedia multiple times in a project intended to be embedded in different sites, so this is causing a significant user experience impact)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: I filled up WebKit bug for this https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=210104

Comment: Hello RYFN, Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Dean nope, we dropped support for Safari instead. :(

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer as to what specifically is going on with browser vendors making iframe getUserMedia requests reprompt for permission every time a media stream is requested, but we found the solution to be to use the parents mediaDevices singleton to request for a stream.

```
function getRootWindow(window) {
    if (window.parent === window) {
        return window;
    }

    return getRootWindow(window.parent);
}

getRootWindow(window).navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia().then(...);
```

We have tested this on iOS, FF, Chrome, Safari and it works fine, once permissions have been granted subsequent requests for a media device work fine. Something about calling this from the iFrames DOM causes it to issue prompts every request.

Comment: Unfortunately the question asks about "Cross domain iframe", this won't work there.

Comment: Kaiido is correct, this solution only works when the iframe doesn't load resources from another origin, however this does work for sandboxxed widgets that you want to run in a separate iframe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same issue even for the same domain iframe - simply asking for `getUserMedia` from inside iframe always asks for permission.

I figured out an ugly workaround even for cross-domain: if you **at least once** ask for permission on "host" page, it'll start working inside iframe. It requires you to have some "host page" script that'll communicate with iframe (via window messages to avoid cross-domain issues) but it works.

Another weird behavior even using my workaround is that `enumerateDevices` do not return valid device names if you first ask a permission on host page and then inside iframe. So a full workaround (if you need enumeration) would be to have 2 permission prompts:

1. first ask inside iframe (this will make sure enumeration works)
2. and then on host page (this will ensure Safari will remember permission and won't show prompt for next `getUserMedia` invokes)